# Finding values from a nested object

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array like so:

```
[
 {
  lookups: [], 
  rows: [{data: {a: 1, b: 2}}, {data: {a: 3, b: 4}}], 
  title: "Table 1", 
  columns: [{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}]
 },
 {
  lookups: [],
  rows: [{data: {c: 5, d: 6}}, {data: {c: 7, d: 8}}],
  title: "Table 2",
  columns: [{name: "c"}, {name: "d"}]
 }
]
```

After I select the correct object (which I am using `Array.find()` using the title to do). I need to be able to go through the rows array and try to get each value for a particular string that I have (e.g. If I have a string value of "a" then I would like to get the values 1 and 3 back).

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple mapping. Suppose you have property name stored in variable named `prop`

```
data = obj.rows.map(({data}) => data[prop])
```